# Python Progressbar (PyPi) - display custom text that changes with update()

Tags: python, progress-bar

Hey I am using the progressbar package from pypi and i really like it a lot. My problem is that I haven't found a way so far to display custom text. What I mean with that is displaying text that changes when I call `pbar.update()`

For example if i scan my computer recursively for files I want the progress bar to change to the current file.

```
widgets = [CustomText(), ' ', Percentage(), ' ', Bar('/'), ' ', RotatingMarker()]
pbar = ProgressBar(widgets=widgets, maxval=1000)
pbar.start()

pbar.update(0, "custom_string")
```

Something like this would work out best for me. But since the update function only takes a number I am not sure how to implement something like this without changing progress bar library itself.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I tried to use `update` method in the `FormatLabel` widget to change the contents of the label, but it didn't work for me. However, replacing the `FormatLabel` with a completely new object worked for me:

```
from progressbar import *
import time

widgets = [FormatLabel(''), ' ', Percentage(), ' ', Bar('/'), ' ', RotatingMarker()]
progressbar = ProgressBar(widgets=widgets, maxval=10)
progressbar.start()
for i in range(0, 11):
    widgets[0] = FormatLabel('<filename-{0}>'.format(i))
    progressbar.update(i)
    time.sleep(.5)
progressbar.finish()
```

Comment: works great thanks a lot, i did look at format label, but was not aware that progress bar rechecks the widgets every time it updates, thanks again

Comment: If applying to the end, be sure to update term_width to include the length of the custom text:  bar.term_width = 50 + len(formatLabel)